# SCM-Manager for SVN + Nginx + HTTPS

Tags: svn, version-control, repository, scmmanager

I would like to setup SCM-Manager over HTTPS. I have made an installation on a Debian. I use SCM-Manager with a local IP and over HTTP. Nginx is the proxy and transform the request into HTTPS.

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080 https://repo.mydomain.org;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
```

Here is the SCM configuration :

```
<base-url>https://repo.mydomain.org/</base-url>

server-config.xml => <Set name="contextPath">/scm</Set>
                  => <Set name="forwarded">true</Set>
                  => <SystemProperty name="jetty.host" default="127.0.0.1" />
```

Everything works fine, but I have a mistake when I want to see a diff or file. The URL to get content stills on HTTP instead of HTTPS. Here is the output from the different browsers (Firefox, Chrome, IE):

From Chrome:

> Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://repo.mydomain.org/#contentPanel;BQPsols4p3;null;trunk/init.php;content'
>   was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest
>   endpoint
>   'http://repo.mydomain.org/api/rest/repositories/BQPsols4p3/content/?path=trunk/init.php&_dc=1470349149784'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Why does the system try to get the data over HTTP instead of HTTPS?

Another small mistke is that the software try to get this language scripts, but they don't exist on the server.

```
/resources/moment/lang/fr.js
/resources/extjs/i18n/ext-lang-fr.js
/resources/js/i18n/fr.js
/resources/moment/lang/fr.js
/resources/extjs/i18n/ext-lang-fr.js
/resources/js/i18n/fr.js
```

How to remove theses 404?

**EDIT**

Here is the complete configuration of Nginx :

```
user www-data;
#worker_processes auto;
worker_processes  4;
worker_rlimit_nofile  20480;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 8192;
    use epoll;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile off;
    tcp_nopush off;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    server_tokens off;

    client_body_timeout   60s;
    client_header_timeout 60s;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_comp_level 1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ssl   off;

    upstream scm {
        server 127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

     server {
           listen       80 default;
           server_name  _;
           #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

           location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js|mov|swf|dcr)$ {
               root  /home/www/public_html;
               access_log   off;
               expires      30d;
           }

           location / {
               root  /home/www/public_html;
           }

           location ~ /\.ht {
               deny  all;
           }

           location /nginx_status {
               stub_status on;
               access_log off;
               allow 127.0.0.1;
               deny all;
           }
    }


    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Site enabled (lastest config test) :

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  repv.mydomain.org;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  repv.mydomain.org;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate     /home/ssl/letsencrypt/live/repv.mydomain.org/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/ssl/letsencrypt/live/repv.mydomain.org/privkey.pem;

    ssl_stapling            on;
    ssl_stapling_verify     on;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /home/ssl/letsencrypt/live/repv.mydomain.org/fullchain.pem;

    ssl_ciphers               "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
    ssl_protocols             TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache         shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout       5m;
    ssl_dhparam               /home/ssl/private/dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ http://$host$1/ permanent;

        proxy_pass http://scm;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
        proxy_redirect http://scm https://repv.mydomain.org;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ctx "";
    }

}
```

And the proxy.conf :

```
proxy_redirect          off;
proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_hide_header       X-Powered-By;
client_max_body_size        20m;
client_body_buffer_size     1024k;
send_timeout                90;
proxy_connect_timeout       90;
proxy_send_timeout          90;
proxy_read_timeout          90;
proxy_buffer_size           16k;
proxy_buffers               8 32k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size     64k;
proxy_temp_file_write_size  64k;
proxy_buffering             on;
proxy_http_version          1.1;
```

**EDIT 2**

I have tried to switch to HTTP. But I have the same problem. When I want to view a file or a diff, I have the message "The resource could not be found". The reason is that the called ajax ressource return a 404 error with no content.

Example: "http://repo.mydomain.org/api/rest/repositories/BQPsols4p3/content/?path=trunk/init.php&revision=30&_dc=1472061397498" returns a 404... ; and the same for raw view "http://repo.mydomain.org/api/rest/repositories/BQPsols4p3/content/?path=trunk/init.php&revision=30" returns a 404.

Can you help me to find the problem?

Thank you for your help,

Stéphane

Comment: This very strange, because scm-manager uses relative urls for every request. Could you please post the /etc/nginx/proxy.conf file?

Comment: The I18n files are loaded based on the primary locale of your browser. If the primary locale is not english scm-manager tries to find locale files for your primary language and overwrites the ui label with the ones from the i18n files. If the files could not be found (the 404 errors), scm-manager will fallback to english.

Comment: I have edited the answer, please find the configuration file. Ok for 404, but I find this method not very clean. It's better to use a dict with available languages and try to display browser language with a default language if it does not exist. Thanks.

Comment: I have edited the answer to add more information about the mistake without https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to have all the stack working.

First, I have removed the line from Nginx:

```
rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ http://$host$1/ permanent;
```

Next, I have changed the rights on my SVN files '/home/local/svn' with a 'chown -Rc scm:scm /home/local/svn'.

And finally, as I migrate from an old SVN server 1.6, I have activated the Pre 1.6 option in SCM Manager (don't forget to reboot your server).

All works fine for now!

Hope this can be helpful for someone :)